# Trusted Advisor: Amazon EBS Snapshots issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, elastic-beanstalk

I am  trying to follow Trusted Advisor and resolve problem with Amazon EBS Snapshots. My problem is in state

> Red: The volume does not have a snapshot

Currently I have 9 different environments created in Elastic Beanstalk that are hosting some java apps. Every time I update my environment a new volume is created and in the end Trusted Advisor is screaming because of missing snapshot. Do I really need snapshots for them? What for?

Does Elastic Beanstalk provide any way to configure automatic snapshots?

I cannot exclude these volumes from Advisor because I am only able to exclude currently existing instances and as I said after every update I have new ones :(

Comment: The easiest option is probably to go in and manually take a snapshot. A quick Google didn't show any way to take automatic snapshots within Beanstalk, but I don't know a lot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trusted advisor is really just that, advice. It is making assumption based on AWS best practices. A snapshot is AWS's way to backup your ebs-backed instances. If you are not concerned about backups or data on those instances then you do not need to worry about snapshots. IF you do then it is advisable to perform backups to enable the Recovery point objective.

> You can back up the data on your Amazon EBS volumes to Amazon S3 by taking point-in-time snapshots. Snapshots are incremental backups, which means that only the blocks on the device that have changed after your most recent snapshot are saved.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html

More information about Trusted Advisor can be found at the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/faqs/#Trusted_Advisor)

You can create scheduled Lambda functions to create ebs snapshots
Here is a [great tutorial.](https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/) Also AWS has a guide on how to implement an [EBS snapshot scheduler.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ebs-snapshot-scheduler/welcome.html)

Comment: The likelihood of an EBS volume failure scales with the amount of un-snapshotted data. The scheduler above can take care of auto-creating them. That said, if your nodes are disposable then you don't need that extra reliability and can safely ignore it.